# Call class method inside a callback function

Tags: javascript

I have the following class. It has a bug since this reference at this.handlers (line 2) is different from this in this.setTimeRange (line 4)

```
function Synchronized() {
    this.handlers = [];
    $("#masterSlider").rangeSlider();

    $("#masterSlider").bind("valuesChanging", function(e, data) {
        this.setTimeRange(data.values.min, data.values.max);
    });

}

Synchronized.prototype = {
    setTimeRange: function(lowerBound, upperBound) {
        console.log(lowerBound, upperBound);
        this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
        $("#masterSlider").rangeSlider("bounds", this.lowerBound, this.upperBound);
    },
}
```

How could I call class method from a callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.  The three most common ones:

Create a variable to store a copy of `this` that you can close over

```
var that = this;
$("#masterSlider").bind("valuesChanging", function(e, data) {
    that.setTimeRange(data.values.min, data.values.max);
});
```

Use `function.prototype.bind` on your anonymous function to return another function which has a specified value of `this`:

```
$("#masterSlider").bind("valuesChanging", (function(e, data) {
    this.setTimeRange(data.values.min, data.values.max);
}).bind(this));
```

Use an ES6 arrow function instead of an anonymous function:

```
$("#masterSlider").bind("valuesChanging", (e, data) => this.setTimeRange(data.values.min, data.values.max));
```

Comment: Please flag as a duplicate if it's already linked.

Answer (score 1):

you should save the function reference before you enter to the callback and loose the reference. so one solution is like this :

```
   var self = this;
   $("#masterSlider").bind("valuesChanging", function(e, data) {
  self.setTimeRange(data.values.min, data.values.max);
 });
```